# Verification of proof of continuity between metric spaces and deduction from proof

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $M = [0,1]^{[0,1]}$ and $d(f,g) = \sup{\{\lvert f(x) - g(x)\rvert \mid x \in [0,1]\}}$.

For $a,b \in [0,1]$ let $\phi_{a,b}(f) = f(b) - f(a)$ ($\phi$ maps from $M \to \Bbb{R}$). Assume that $\Bbb{R}$ uses the standard metric.

We must show that the maps $\phi_{a,b}$ are continuous. Can someone please verify that my proof below is correct?

We wish to show that $\forall$ $f_1 \in M$ $\forall$ $\epsilon \gt 0$ $\exists$ $\delta \gt 0 $ such that $\forall$ $f_2 \in M$ we have that:

$d(f_1,f_2) \lt \delta \implies \lvert \phi_{a,b}(f_1) - \phi_{a,b}(f_2) \rvert \lt \epsilon$

Suppose that $\epsilon \gt 0$ is given. Set $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then, $\forall f_1, f_2 \in M$ such that $d(f_1,f_2) = \sup{\{\lvert f_1(x) - f_2(x)\rvert \mid x \in [0,1]\}} \lt \delta$

We have that: $\lvert \phi_{a,b}(f_1) - \phi_{a,b}(f_2) \rvert = \lvert f_1(b) - f_1(a) - f_2(b) + f_2(a) \rvert = \lvert (f_1(b) - f_2(b)) + (f_2(a) - f_1(a)) \rvert \le \lvert f_1(b) - f_2(b) \rvert + \lvert f_1(a) - f_2(a) \rvert$

However, we have that $0 \le \lvert f_1(b) - f_2(b) \rvert \le \sup{\{\lvert f_1(x) - f_2(x)\rvert \mid x \in [0,1]\}} \lt \delta$ $\forall b \in [0,1]$.

Thus, $\lvert \phi_{a,b}(f_1) - \phi_{a,b}(f_2) \rvert \lt \delta + \delta = \epsilon$. Hence, $\phi_{a,b}$ is continuous $\forall a,b \in [0,1]$ $QED$

Is this proof correct? I think I have made a mistake somewhere. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** Also, is there a nice way to deduce the following from the above proof?

Let $X = \{f \in M \mid \forall a,b \in [0,1], a \le b : f(b) - f(a) \ge 0\}$  (the set of increasing functions). Show that X is a $d$-closed subset of $M$.

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Comment: The triangle inequality for distances derived from norms may be used in two ways: the "standard" $\| x-y \| \le \| x-z \| + \| z-y \|$ and the less frequent but equally correct $\| x \| = \| x-y + y \| \le \| x-y \| + \| y \|$ which gives $\| x \| - \| y \| \le \| x-y \|$, which is the one that you use above. This means, in particular, that your proof is essentially correct (I haven't checked the minute details).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you use your choice of $\delta$ to conclude that $|\phi_{a,b}(f_1) - \phi_{a,b}(f_2)| < \epsilon$? I think you need to use the (non-reverse) triangle inequality here, i.e.: pick $\delta = \epsilon/2$, and argue that

$$\begin{align*} |\phi_{a,b}(f_1) - \phi_{a,b}(f_2)| &= |f_1(b) - f_1(a) -f_2(b) + f_2(a)| \\ &\leq |f_1(b) - f_2(b)| + |f_1(a) - f_2(a)| \\ &\leq 2\sup|f_1(x) - f_2(x)| \\ &< 2\delta \\ &= \epsilon.\end{align*}$$

To answer your edit: you have that $$X = \{f \in M \mid \forall a \leq b, \phi_{a,b}(f) \geq 0 \} = \bigcap_{a \leq b}\phi_{a,b}^{-1}([0,1]).$$

As each $\phi_{a,b}$ is continuous, the preimage of each closed set $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed, and the arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I had a feeling that there was a mistake somewhere in that argument, I did the triangle inequality the wrong way. Thanks!

Comment: @LaurenHayes I answered your edit too.

Comment: I am a little confused about the answer to the second part, however, I think I am starting to understand it. We are taking taking the intersection of sets which contain functions which map to values between 0 and 1 under the $\phi$ maps on a particular $a$ and $b$ and so we end up with the functions which give a positive value for all $a \le b$ on input to the respective $\phi$ map?

Comment: Also, would I be correct in saying that the decreasing functions would be given by:

$$\bigcap_{a \le b} \phi^{-1}_{a,b}([-1,0])$$

Comment: @LaurenHayes Yes, essentially. Since each $\phi_{a,b}$ depends on a particular choice of a pair of points $(a,b)$, we need some way to look at *all* the pairs where $a \leq b$ at once, and the intersection lets us do precisely that.

Comment: @LaurenHayes Yes, you would be absolutely correct!

Comment: Perfect, I think I have an understanding of it now. Thanks for much for your help :)

Comment: Would you have any hint or starting piece of help to show that the above metric space is compact/not-compact?

Comment: @LaurenHayes Do you mean $M$ or $X$?

Comment: Apologies, $(M,d)$. I am aware of the fact that compactness is equivalent to (completeness & total boundedness) and sequential compactness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33780/discussion-between-a-p-and-lauren-hayes).